# Possible to prevent a function from running when it's initiated by a button click?

Tags: javascript

I have a Chrome extension that I made that runs on an internal site that is very similar to Zillow, so I will use that as an example. If you go to a Zillow property and "connect" it to the extension via an injected button, basically saying you want to add it to your list of tracked properties, the intended behavior is that the next time you load up the property, one of the existing buttons is modified via `innerText`. Right now, when you connect the property by clicking the button to do so, immediately the existing button's text is changed on the screen, even though there are a lot of other functions that are not possible to perform until at least 1 page reload.

What I am trying to do is allow the user to connect the property, and the text of the  existing button does not do anything at this time, but only after the page is reloaded, then it will change as it should.

```
var propertyInject = async function () { 
propertyDetail = await g_group.get(propertyId);

if(groupDetail) {

document.arrive('[aria-label="Tax data"] { existing: true, fireOnAttributesModification: true,    onceOnly: false },
    async function (ele) {
        if(ele.querySelector('span :last-child').innerText != "Analyze taxes")
        ele.querySelector('span :last-child').innerText = "Analyze taxes";

})
}
}
```

The existing code works great when the page is loaded up (the button text changes as normal) but when you connect the property, it immediately sees that the button meets the requirement to update the text, and it does so immediately. I am trying for it to not change this when the property is added, but only after the page is loaded every time after that.

Any suggestions?

P.S. If you see any syntax errors in the above code, I quickly cobbled that together in notepad because there is a lot of other unnecessary/unrelated stuff that would make make it way more annoying to see what's going on, so I quickly removed all that. Apologies in advance.

Comment: Ahhh probably would be a better idea to show more of your code. If you knew where the error was then you wouldnt be asking for help.

Comment: @GetSet there is no error in my functional code, I was saying I might have made an error condensing it down for this post to remove all the extra stuff that is for other functions. there might not be one, I was just explaining why there might be one, and that if there is, it's not in my working code, it would only be here accidentally. 

My existing code works fine, I am just trying to add to it to work in a different way, as stated in the original post.

Comment: For example, how does `groupDetail` get its value? Not shown in the code you excerpted.  Yet that value seems important enough to condition the remaining of the code you did excerpt. Unless of course, thats a bug you didnt notice.